# Accessing more data from a 403 response

Tags: .net, vb.net, http

I've an application that's uploading data to a server. Occasionally the server returns a 403 response from a call to HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(). The response contains more data than simply the response code, but I can't figure out how to access it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() yet?  The HttpWebResponse class provides access to that information.

Comment: GetResponse seems to do a similar thing. It throws an Exception and so doesn't return a HttpWebResponse object.

Comment: If a WebException is being thrown, then you can use the WebException.Response property to access the response info.

Comment: Ah, fantastic, hadn't noticed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what follows is just the text of the why the server sent back a 403:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html